# SimpleCov: load .resultset.json and output html

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simplecov

I would like to load a .resultset.json file and output the index.html that simplecov does when you run the test. I have not had success doing merging - it seems to only have the last result in the html coverage summary. I can create a resultset.json with multiple different keys and coverage under them, and I'd like to generate the html.

Comment: Please add any solution if you find any.

Comment: I kinda had some success with a slightly different approach - We are starting to use CircleCI, and we run a script modified from one I found for CircleCI coverage merging. The place I found it is at https://gist.github.com/leemachin/1aeb217d989f3981cc3f06d88938bd33, and my code doesn't change any of the relevant parts.